# Make a button expand and collapse in map function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, render

I am working on a project as a means to practice some stuff in react and I need to render a button for each of the map data. I did this successfully but expand and collapse has been giving me issue. Whenever I click on the button all data collapse and expand together.

```
const DataFetch = () => {
 ...
  const [btnValue, setBtnValue] = useState('+');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setShowData(!showData);
    setBtnValue(btnValue === '+' ? '-' : '+');
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      ...
      {studentResults
        .filter((val) => {
          if (searchTerm === '') {
            return val;
          } else if (
            val.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
            val.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            return val;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .map((student) => {
          return (
            <div key={student.id}>
              <div className='card'>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='col-2'>
                    <div className='pic'>
                      <img src={student.pic} alt='avatar' />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='col'>
                    <div className='details'>
                      <p className='name'>
                        {student.firstName.toUpperCase()}{' '}
                        {student.lastName.toUpperCase()}
                      </p>
                      <div className='sub-details'>
                        <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
                        <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
                        <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
                        <p>
                          Average:{' '}
                          {student.grades.reduce(
                            (a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b),
                            0
                          ) /
                            student.grades.length +
                            '%'}
                        </p>
                        <button onClick={handleChange} className='showBtn'>
                          {btnValue}
                        </button>
                        {showData  && (
                          <div>
                            <br />
                            {student.grades.map((grade, key) => {
                              return (
                                <p key={key}>
                                  Test {key + 1}: &emsp; {grade}%
                                </p>
                              );
                            })}
                          </div>
                        )}
...
```

**Collapse Image**
[image]

**Expand Image**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the elements expand and collapse together because you assign to all of them the same state `showData` state.

One solution would be to add a new field to your data (so inside `student`) that is `true` or `false` when you want to expand or collapse the single student.

Another solution would be to create the `showData` state as an array where each element correspond to a different `student`. When you click the button, in this case, you pass to the function for example the `id` and with that you link your `student` to the right element inside the `showData`.